# Static Var Missing argument for parameter "coder"

Tags: swift, static, var

I have a class with a webview and I would like to add a static var, i already did this with other class and it's working but now i don't now why, but i have a error about "coder" argument :

```
 class Actu: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate  {

class var myInstance : Actu{
    struct Static {
        static let myInstanceActu : Actu = Actu() //Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call
    }
    return Static.myInstanceActu
}
       required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let scriptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hideSectionsActu", ofType: "js")
    let scriptContent = String(contentsOfFile:scriptURL!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent!, injectionTime: .AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

}
```

}

if someone has a idea, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you do not have any initializer that takes no argument. Try adding below initializer and it should work.

```
init () {
   // Your initialization
}
```

EDIT : Post OP comments - Per Apple Documentation:

> “A designated initializer must ensure that all of the “properties
>   introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a
>   superclass initializer.”

Comment: I did it and the error disappeared, i override init and add a super.init(). Now it told me that "Property 'self.webview' not initialised at super.init call"

Comment: it's ok that was easy. And thanks again for your answer, that was really helpful

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers:)!